# auto-filling website forms mac apps

Tags: macos, cocoa, sdk

I'm pretty new to the Mac SDK, but I can find my way around the basics easily enough. There is one thing I'm stumped on however: I am trying to make an app where it automatically goes into a webpage when it becomes available, e.g. for concert ticket sales and such. I have the app set up to accept the users' id and password, but how to I push that to the website and fill in the log in form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the website into a [`WebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and use JavaScript to manipulate and submit the form:

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```